# Reload data on map fragment/viewmodel from database c#

Tags: c#, database, database-design, viewmodel, mvvmcross

I have an issue concerning updating data that appears on my fragment. So I currently have a mobile application built using mvvm cross. In a view model I have a function named:

```
public async Task InitializeData()
```

In this function I am making the calls to the database through a web service ASP.NET project. The web service then communicates with the database. So my issue is that in my fragment which is called "MapFragment". I load my data onto the map whenever the user navigates to the map page once but if there is a change in the db from another user it will not reflect in the application's map because It only does it once in InitializeData. It appears in the database I can see the change but in order to see the change in the map I need to reload the application which is not what I want. Basically if there is a change in the database I want to be able to call InitalizeData again I believe, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: Just call the method? It is not entirely clear where you get notified about the database change. I suspect you change the database yourself, so just call it from there?

Comment: I call the database inside the function InitalizaData like so: _allobjects = await _objectDataService.GetObjects();. So basically this function is called at the beginning the application so we start off with this data but if for example a user adds a data to the dB by creating an object using a function somewhere else in the app. I want to be notified and be able to Initalizedata again

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Easiest way would be to broadcast a message using MessageHub (IMvxMessenger) and listen to that in the places you want to refresh data.

Comment: may I have a link on what you are referring to? or on other ways I'm quite nooby